# SQL Query to get mapping of all users to their logins

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

What's a query that I can use to get a list of all logins associated with each user in SQL Azure?

So far I've found the following two queries to get all users and all logins, but I haven't found any way to see which user goes with which login:

```
SELECT * from sys.sql_logins -- get all logins
SELECT * from sys.sysusers -- get all users
```

In case you find it helpful, here's the documentation for the structures of those the tables:

**sys.sql_logins:** 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174355.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**Column names:** name, principal_id, sid, type, type_desc, is_disabled, create_date, modify_date, default_database_name, default_language_name, credential_id, is_policy_checked, is_expiration_checked, password_hash

**sys.sysusers:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179871.aspx

**Column names:** uid, status, name, sid, roles, createdate, updatedate, altuid, password, gid, environ, hasdbaccess, islogin, isntname, isntgroup, isntuser, issqluser, isaliased, issqlrole, isapprole

Comment: can you show each table structure?

Comment: There is hopefully a key in either the logins table or the users table that links them together. Then you would perform a join on that key. If you show us the columns in the tables, we should be able to figure it out

Comment: @SariRahal these are default SQL system tables, I'm not customizing anything. But I've added the links to the official docs describing their structure

Comment: @kbball these are default SQL system tables, I'm not customizing anything. But I've added the column names and links to the official docs describing their structure. Thanks for helping

Comment: @ZainRizvi I have updated my answer.  You can do the JOIN on the column "sid".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell you your correct answer b/c we don't know the structure of your tables.  If you share that we can help more.  But below should get you to where you need to go.

They way to do it is by a MySQL JOIN.  In this case you should use a INNER or OUTER JOIN depending on how your database is structured.

If you have 2 tables that are structured below you can do an FULL OUTER JOIN

[sys.sql_logins]

```
| sid| userID |  name   |
| 1  | 1      |  ssmith |
| 2  | 2      |  bbob   |
```

[sys.sysusers]

```
| sid| name      | 
| 1  | Sam Smith |  
| 2  | Billy Bob |
```

You can use the following query to do it

```
SELECT A.name as userName, B.name as login 
FROM sys.sysusers A 
     FULL OUTER JOIN sys.sql_logins B 
     ON A.sid = B.sid
```

This will result in :

```
| userName   | logins |
| Same Smith | ssmith |
| Billy Bob  | bbob   |
```

Here is a link to more types of MySQL Joins

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks.  I'm very familiar with SQL joins but I didn't understand what the sid column was nor that it could be used to do the join.

Comment: NP.  The sid was a Foreign Key that was located in both tables.  That is why we were able to JOIN the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can join on the sid, try this (but maybe just select whatever columns you want):

```
select l.*, u.*
from sys.sql_logins l
join sys.sysusers u on l.sid = u.sid
```